# how to make xulrunner with python

Tags: python, xul, xulrunner

I want make a stand application use python and xulrunner, but I am very confused, I use 
[pyxpcomext](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/downloads.html) with xulrunner 1.9.1,and it can word,

but with python logic can not import pyd? I used lxml in this app. In lxml there is a etree.pyd.and can not import it.

But I saw a [Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/), it is xulrunner and python. I want rebuild my app like Miro, can any one give me some point? and how to build to make a framework like Miro.

thanks~

Comment: Please rewrite your question to adhere to at least basic standards, both in terms of writing and the detail with which you describe your specific problem. As of now, it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Jim: He seems to be a non-english speaker, geez.
Please post your code, and if you can, please clean up your post so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions. Zero in on one, e.g. the pyd one.